# Most efficient way to draw large number of the same objects, but with different transforms

Tags: opengl

I'd like to draw a large number (multiple thousands) of simple meshes (each maybe... a maximum of 50 triangles, but even that is a very large upper bound), all of which are exactly the same.

As a simple brute force way, right now I'm just doing thousands of draw calls, where I just change the transformation matrices that the shaders need and then draw the same objects again.

Of course this is hideously slow, since (I'm guessing) there are too many draw calls for the driver and my PC to handle efficiently.

What can I do to make it faster?

Comment: I can't give you a complete answer, but the high-level answer is to use [geometry instancing](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_instancing).

Comment: Search google for "Geometry Instancing", maybe you can find something that helps you that way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution to this is instancing. [This tutorial](http://sol.gfxile.net/instancing.html) explains a few methods of instancing. If you have `ARB_draw_instanced` and `ARB_instanced_arrays`, use them.

The general idea is to store all of your meshes' transforms in a separate buffer object and bind that to an attribute array that uses one "vertex" per instance via `glVertexAttribDivisor`.

If, after that, you're still not running as fast as you want to, you're probably vertex processor bound. Do frustum culling on the meshes, and preferably build a [BVH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy) to traverse instead of doing the cull on all the meshes independently.

Comment: +1; with many thousands of objects you may also become CPU-bound on the transforms (just sending position and rotation in your per-instance buffer and computing the per-object matrix on the GPU can help here), and don't forget to watch how you update that dynamic vertex buffer!

Comment: @Robert Rouhani: Thanks, I've researched and promptly implemented it. Now I can draw 5000 meshes with 20 tris each at 250 FPS. By the way, your suggested way seems a bit outdated. Since OpenGL 3.something geometry instancing is official part of the OpenGL core specification, no need for ARB_xxx anymore. I use a uniform buffer to store the matrices, and use glDrawElementsInstanced. Inside the vertex shader, there's a layout(std140) uniform matrices { mat4 array[5000]; } where I can access the relevant element via array[gl_InstanceID]

Comment: @TravisG I tend to try and support older versions. I understand both those extensions have been promoted to core for a while, the extension string will still be present, however :). Also, using `glVertexAttribDivisor` (which is not deprecated or outdated by any means) has the benefit of not having an upper limit on instance count. Performance has been historically better than uniform buffers, but is probably the same or very similar now, and both ways get the job done.

Comment: @Robert Rouhani: Mhm... I guess it's true. Someone with outdated drivers could support ARB_xxx but not official core OpenGl 3.x features. I'll take a look at glVertexAttribDivisor, thanks.

Comment: @Robert Rouhani: I implemented both versions (using uniform buffers, and alternatively your suggested version where I use a vertex attribute that only changes once per instance), and the uniform buffer version is actually about twice as fast (4000 fps in release mode, vs ~2000 with glVertexAttribDivisor, the 250 fps number was only for CPU-side).

Comment: How are you updating the instance vertex buffer? And also make sure you're using `GL_STREAM_DRAW` as your usage hint. Also, framerate is a terrible performance metric, those are almost the same. The difference between 4k FPS and 2k FPS is 0.25 ms, a little less than the difference between 60 and 61 FPS.

Comment: @RobertRouhani Sorry for the late answer, I forgot to answer when you initially commented. When I tested it, I tested different methods of updating the vertex buffer and also the transforms buffer (e.g. just generating it once with STATIC_DRAW and leaving it unchanged, or updating it every frame with STREAM_DRAW or DYNAMIC_DRAW) but the results were the same. Of course this was a test limited in scope, there was nothing going on besides the instanced rendering test, so that might have influenced it.